# input Vowel then sum ASCII Value of Consonants in between

Tags: java

I've hit a brick wall on this program

```
public class Assignment11 {


public int sumConstants ()
{
   char ch = 'A';

   for (int i = 0 ; i<=90 && i >= 65 ; i++)
   {
         if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
    {
         int x = (int) ch;

    }
   }

    return ch;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in );

    Assignment11 a11 = new Assignment11();

    int x = a11.sumConstants();

    System.out.println("Enter TWO upper case Characters:");

    String s = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("The sum of the constants is: " + x);


}

}
```

This is the output I End up with

```
Enter TWO upper case Characters:
AE
The sum of the constants is: 65
```

An example of the output I would like is :

```
Enter TWO upper case Characters:
IO
The sum of the constants is: 380
```

So basically what happend is that the ASCII values of"JKLMN" were added together.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your output.  A+E definitely does not sum to 65.  I think that's the value for A alone.  And IO couldn't sum to 380, the sum should be around 150 or so.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your wanted output? Seems not so clear to me.

Comment: I'm trying to add all the consonants between A and E @markspace

Comment: You mean you're trying to sum the ASCII values of B,C and D?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. @markspace

Comment: What is all that junk about month and day in numeric form?

Comment: Yes.... It's another form of me getting used to the ASCII values so i don't have to rely on the Chart. @markspace

Comment: Plus I'm trying to use a simple code as well....

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm confused sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 arguments to your method and pass the 2 characters to the method:

```
public static int sumConsonants(char start, char end){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int x=start+1; x<end; x++){
        if(!Character.toString((char)x).matches("[aeiouAeiou]+"))  //if is consonant
            sum += x;                                              //add to sum
    }           
    return sum;
}
```

**Complete run:**

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
char start = scn.nextLine().charAt(0);
char end = scn.nextLine().charAt(0);
System.out.println("The sum of the constants is: " + sumConsonants(start, end));
```

---

**Test:**

```
System.out.pritln(sumConsonants('A', 'E'));  //66 + 67 + 68
```

**Output:**

```
201
```

Comment: @markspace Alright, I will edit it. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: @dude87 Take a look at my solution.

Comment: @user3437460 it works perfectly.... Thank you very Much.........**Plus anyone Else who had some Input Thank You** =D

Comment: @dude87 Glad to help ;)